# Каст пустой строки в инт

Tags: postgresql

Как преобразовать пустую строку в цифру 0?
Вот пример:

```
SELECT ''::INTEGER;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 1: select ''::INTEGER;
```

Единственное решение, пришедшее в голову, выглядит немного громоздко:

```
SELECT(CASE WHEN my_val = '' THEN '0' ELSE my_val END)::INTEGER;
```

Может есть способ покороче?

Нагуглил такое, вопрос прежний)

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(my_val, ''), '0')::INTEGER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Это преобразует пустую строку в число 0:

```
select regexp_replace(text1, '^$', '0')
```

Например,

```
create table samples(
  text1 text
);

insert into samples(text1) values
  (''),
  ('   '),
  ('a'),
  ('b c'),
  ('456'),
  ('   123');

select text1, 
       regexp_replace(text1, '^$', '0') as replace_empty_0, 
       regexp_replace(text1, '^\s*$', '0') as replace_onlyspaces_0
  from samples;
```

В знак соответствия регулярному выражению:

1. `^` означает начало текста
2. `$` означает конец текста
3. `\s*` означает любое количество пробелов

Comment: если честно я не понимаю принцип работы, можно пояснение?)

Comment: заменяет пустую строку на строку '0'

Comment: Я добавил объяснение в ответ